# Using Sharepoint URL without port number

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping, host-header

I have a sharepoint web application like so:`http://intranet:8080`
 I don't want to use port 80.
 But i want users to type URL `http://intranet instead of http://intranet:8080`
 How can i achieve this?
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using Alternate Access Mapping:

1. On the Alternate Access Mappings page (Central Administration), click Edit Public URLs.
2. If the mapping collection that you want to modify is not specified, then choose one.
3. In the Alternate Access Mapping Collection section, 
   click Change alternate access mapping collection on the Alternate Access Mapping Collection menu.
4. On the Select an Alternate Access Mapping Collection page, click a mapping collection.
5. In the Public URLs section, you may add new URLs or edit existing URLs in any of the following text boxes: Default, Intranet, or you can change the Default from **abc:555**  to **abctest** 
   Click Save.
6. Now you’ll have to switch over to your DNS server.
7. Within the DNS Management Console and Under Forward Lookup Zones:

   - Add a new Primary Zone with your new domain name.
   - Add a new Host (A) to the records for **abctest** and point the IP Address to         the sharepoint server

Source: Internet

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this in many ways it all depends on your infrastructure capabilities, here is my take:

1. Extend you existing application on a HOST-HEADER based web
   application - that would create a new IIS web site too, and you
   would need to use port 80.
2. Use a reverse-proxy such as ForeFront TMG, ISA 2006 or any other that could be configured to forward all requests to the right SharePoint WFE and update headers. Make sure you test properly configuration as I've had bad experience with F5 networks in terms of Session Afinity, Headers changing, etc. which could trouble SharePoint and make you loose functionality particularly in post-backs. You might need to update AAM

Answer (score 1):

That is not directly a SharePoint question.
However, you can create a new IIS Website on port 80 with host header "intranet" and then activate a redirect to intranet:8080. So the user can enter intranet but will be redirected to 8080.
All links within SharePoint remain on port 8080.
Why do you dont want to use port 80?

Comment: marco is it a good practice to have it on 80?
I didn't want to have it there incase i need to have to use it for something else or custom apps
Let me know your iputs
Cheers

Comment: You can have more than one web site on port 80 on the same machine, by using [host headers](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true) (referencing to IIS6 but also true for newer IIS versions). For SharePoint specific configuration look [here](http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1323)